# How to stream (query) data from BigQuery as source in a Siddhi App

Tags: java, google-bigquery, siddhi

Would like to develop a data processing pipeline application using siddhi (https://siddhi.io/) to read data from BigQuery and generate events. There are many references to use HTTP, RDBMS and TCP as sources, but not sure how exactly we could deal with BigQuery. Any reference or example on how to connect to BigQuery from Siddhi Application as source will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, Siddhi doesn't have a native implementation to support this. A list of currently available extensions is listed [here](https://siddhi.io/en/v5.1/docs/extensions/#siddhi-extensions). You can try writing a custom connector by following [this](https://siddhi.io/en/v5.1/docs/extensions/#writing-custom-extensions) and [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage/libraries#client-libraries-install-java)